# Module not found: Can't resolve 'styled-component'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I created a new react app using `create-react-app` and then installed `styled-component` using `npm`. But when I use it in component, I am getting following error.

> Failed to compile. ./src/Components/Lightbox/styledLightbox.js
>
> Module not found:
>
> Can't resolve 'styled-component' in
>   '/Users/ishan/Documents/react-app/src/Components/Lightbox'

Following is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { LightboxWrapper } from './styledLightbox';

class Lightbox extends Component {

    renderEntry() {
        if (this.props.lightbox.type === "photo") {
         return  <img alt="name" src={this.props.lightbox.entry} />;
        } 
        if (this.props.lightbox.type === "video") {
        return <video src={this.props.lightbox.entry} onLoadedMetadata={(e) => {console.log("Video duration is: "+e.currentTarget.duration) } } autoPlay muted onEnded={() => console.log("Video ended")} width='100%' height='100%' ></video> 
        }
        if(this.props.lightbox.type === "text"){
        return <div> <p className="lightbox text"> {this.props.lightbox.entry} </p> </div>   
        }

    }

    render() {
        let classList = this.props.lightbox.status === true ? "lightbox-wrapper active" : "lightbox-wrapper";
        return ( 
                <LightboxWrapper className={classList}>
                    {/* {this.renderEntry()} */}
                </LightboxWrapper>
         );
    }
}

export default Lightbox;
```

Following is the styled-component created to use it in other component:

```
import styled from "styled-component";

export const LightboxWrapper = styled.div`
      display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background: radial-gradient(
                center, 
                ellipse farthest-corner, 
                rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
                rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%
        );
    .active {
        display: block;
        background: radial-gradient(
            center, 
            ellipse farthest-corner, 
            rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,
            rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 100%
    );
    }
    .active img, .active video {
        max-width: 70%;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: 0 auto;
        opacity: 1;
        /* box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); */
        transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
        animation: fadeInScale 1.2s ease-in-out;
        max-height: 70%;
        width: auto !important;
        position: relative;
        top: 11%;
}
`;
```

Comment: The package name is pluralised `styled-components`.

Comment: You are missing a ‘s’, try import styled from 'styled-components'... also check the name of the dependency you installed

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You are missing an "s" at the end of `styled-components`

```
npm i styled-components
```